# Why does the div not disappear?

Tags: javascript, html

Why when I try and hid a div for an 
operation does it not disappear? It is my understanding that you can hide something using `document.getElementById('something').style.display = "none";`. Yet when I try and do an operation in between showing and hiding it, it does not work.

```js
 function someComplicatedFunction(ms) {
        // This isn't the exact function I am using, 
        // but it has a similar form and the same problem
        let start = new Date().getTime();
        let end = start;
        while (end < start + ms) {
            end = new Date().getTime();
        }
    }
    
    function hideTheOtherDiv() {
     document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "initial";
        console.log("Start");

        someComplicatedFunction(3000);
        
        console.log("end");
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "initial";
        document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "none";
    }
    
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "none";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="div1">One</div>
<div id="div2">Two</div>
<button onclick="hideTheOtherDiv()">Switch</button>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">


</script>

</html>
```

Comment: That `wait` function is so wrong I don't know where to begin :P Have a look at `setTimeout`

Comment: It's _because_ of that silly `wait` function, that keeps the interpreter busy without any interruption. Please go research why this kind of a "wait" function is about the worst thing to possibly come up with.

Comment: Basically the problem is you don't release control back to the browser to render your change.

Comment: Yes, the problem seems to be with wait.  Using setTimeout() would be better here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` method instead of `someComplicatedFunction()` method.

> As **JavaScript only has a single thread and method will execute
>   asynchronously so webpage will be unresponsive while the script is
>   running.** This is the reason we can't see the data changes if use
>   `someComplicatedFunction()` method as dom manipulation done
>   within a `ms` and page become unresponsive while executing that method
>   for 3 seconds.

```js
function hideTheOtherDiv() {

  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "initial";
  console.log("Start");

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("end");
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "initial";
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "none";
  }, 3000);
}

document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "none";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div id="div1">One</div>
  <div id="div2">Two</div>
  <button onclick="hideTheOtherDiv()">Switch</button>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is causing the other function to not allow it to work? Cause in my actual code I have a much more complicated function that has a purpose rather then just waiting

Comment: updated my answer with reason the problem in OP

Answer (score 0):

```
function hideTheOtherDiv() {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "initial";

    setTimeout( function() {
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "initial";  
        document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "none";
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: What is this? What does it do? How does it answer the question?

Comment: @Rob   I wanted to suggest a solution that would work and implement more standard approach.  Implementation of wait with a while loop is not really that good a practice. But you are right.  It doesn't explain why his code breaks when he uses wait(...). I didn't think there was much point to it.